# jetty websocket leak and offline client detection

Tags: java, memory-leaks, websocket, jetty

I am using jetty websocket to connect android device to server on socket and my problem is when device is online every thing is ok sendString() works fine but when device goes offline on that time jetty still writes on that session successfully and no exception happen how i can handle this

this is the method that i write on websocket

also when i run code for 12 hours reserve memory get full and java heap size error occur I think this is because of assigned resources for not really open websockets by the way I store websockets class in hashmap to access this sockets by there ids

```
private void sendClient(final int user_id, String str) {
        boolean isOpen = false;
        for(EventSocket element : users.get(user_id)) {
            if(element.getSession().isOpen()){
                WriteCallback callBack = new WriteCallback() {
                    Connection connection;
                    @Override
                    public void writeSuccess() {
                        try {
                            connection = Eventserver.connectionPool.getConnection();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        PreparedStatement pst = null;
                        try{
                            pst = connection.prepareStatement("update mysql record");
                            pst.setLong(1, user_id);
                            pst.execute();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally
                        {
                            try {
                                if (pst != null) { pst.close(); }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // log this error
                            }
                            try {
                                if (connection != null) {     connection.close(); }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // log this error
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void writeFailed(Throwable arg0) {
                        System.out.print("error on write !!!!!!!");                         
                    }
                };

                element.getSession().getRemote().sendString(str, callBack);
                isOpen = true;
            }

        }
    }
```